# Monotone numerical scheme and entropy solution to conservation laws

Tags: partial-differential-equations, entropy, hyperbolic-equations

**A monotone numerical scheme is when I have two sequences $v=(v_j)_j$, $w=(w_j)_j$, and $v^{(n)} \ge w^{(n)}$ , then $v^{(n+1)} \ge w^{(n+1)}$** , where $ v_j^{(n)}$ is an appoximation of $u(x_j,t_n)$. Or in other words if I have a $2k+1$ **Explicit difference scheme**, then the derivatives at time $t_n$ are **positive**.

Why is a **monotone numerical scheme** a good approximation for an **entropy solution**? Is it because it ensures the **existence of TVD schemes**, which prevent oscillation, or does it have a **direct relationship to the Entropy solution**?

Answer (score 1):

There is a theorem that links *conservative* monotonous schemes for conservation laws to entropy solutions:

> **Theorem.** If a numerical method for the conservation law $u_t + f(u)_x = 0$ is conservative, consistent and monotonous, then
>
> - The scheme is $L^\infty$ stable, and $\|u_h\|_\infty \leq \|u_0\|_\infty$;
> - The scheme is entropic;
> - The scheme is convergent (towards the entropy-satisfying weak solution).

Such a scheme is of order 1, at most.